# Is it possible to change the amount of time a user stays logged in for?

Tags: users, config, session

Our users are getting logged out after 1 day.

Is there a setting that changes how long users’ sessions will last?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! The setting is called [`userSessionDuration`](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-config-generalconfig.html#usersessionduration), and you can set it in your `general.php` config file, on a per-environment basis.

[Here's an explanation](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-helpers-confighelper.html#method-durationinseconds) of the values that you can use for the setting—for posterity: integers (in seconds), a PHP duration expression, an initialized `DateInterval` object, or `0` for "indefinite."

The link above points to the Craft 3 documentation, but [the same setting](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html#usersessionduration) is available in Craft 2.